# hash key md5 to a key of Symfony

Tags: symfony, hash, key, md5

I am developing a project under symfony which has existed for a few years under Wordpress.

I recovered the database.
Wordpress hash key is "md5 phpass"
Example of hash password : $P$BtiX6tWVq572DwrkuiP8SwxRR3QmT.0

I read on the symfony documentation that you could use 2 keys precisely during a migration

password_hashers:

```
    # a hasher used in the past for some users
    legacy:
        algorithm: sha256
        encode_as_base64: false
        iterations: 1

    App\Entity\User:
        # the new hasher, along with its options
        algorithm: sodium
        migrate_from:
            - bcrypt # uses the "bcrypt" hasher with the default options
            - legacy # uses the "legacy" hasher configured above
```

but my problem is that I don't know the value to set for the algorithm

I tried "md5" "sha3" but nothing

Someone knows what I must whrite in security.yaml

Thank for your helps

Comment: I did it, I write hash et verify but i don't know how check for needsRehash 
My Symfony error is : No password hasher has been configured for account "App\Entity\User".

Comment: It's usually better to update the question itself instead of extending the question with comments.  I don't know what `I write hash et verify` means.  Did you write your own [custom password hasher](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/passwords.html#creating-a-custom-password-hasher) for md5?  That should be all your need.